# How systemd Type option affects starting other units?

Tags: systemd, daemon, init, systemd-unit

The man page `systemd.service(5)` explains the `Type` options for services:

> `Type=`
>
> Configures the process start-up type for this service unit.
>   One of `simple`, `forking`, `oneshot`, `dbus`, `notify` or `idle`.
>
> If set to simple (the default if neither `Type=` nor `BusName=`, but
>   `ExecStart=` are specified), it is expected that the process configured
>   with `ExecStart=` is the main process of the service. In this mode, if
>   the process offers functionality to other processes on the system, its
>   communication channels should be installed before the daemon is
>   started up (e.g. sockets set up by systemd, via socket activation), **as
>   systemd will immediately proceed starting follow-up units.**

This implies to me that systemd won't start the units in parallel here. Also here:

> If set to `forking`, it is expected that the process configured with
>   `ExecStart=` will call `fork()` as part of its start-up. The parent
>   process is expected to exit when start-up is complete and all
>   communication channels are set up. The child continues to run as the
>   main daemon process. This is the behavior of traditional UNIX daemons.
>   If this setting is used, it is recommended to also use the `PIDFile=`
>   option, so that systemd can identify the main process of the daemon.
>   **systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the
>   parent process exits.**

In other words, according to this man page systemd executes the service units sequentially? So when systemd activates a daemon process, it waits for it before it activiates follow up units? Doesn't make sense at all.

How `Type` affects the startup procedure of other units?

Comment: When it is talking about "follow-up" units, it is talking about units directed to run sequentially as determined but the unit "Before" and "After" directives.

Comment: If the type is forking, "systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units as soon as the **parent** process exits." "The child continues to run as the **main daemon process**." The child is doing the heavy lifting here, the parent process is expected "to exit when start-up is complete", i.e. pretty quickly.

Comment: @RamanSailopal This makes sense now.